# Stack data structure in Python 3

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, stack

I have implemented a stack in Python 3, and it works well. If anything needs to be improved, I would appreciate the criticism.

```
class Stack:

        def __init__(self):
            self.stack = []

        def isEmpty(self):
            return self.stack == []

        def push(self, data):
            self.stack.append(data)

        def pop(self):
            data = self.stack[-1]
            del self.stack[-1]
            return data

        def peek(self):
            return self.stack[-1]

        def sizeStack(self):
            return len(self.stack)

stack = Stack()
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
stack.push(3)
print(stack.sizeStack())
print("Popped: ", stack.pop())
print("Popped: ", stack.pop())
print(stack.sizeStack())
print("Peek:", stack.peek())
print(stack.sizeStack())
```

Comment: You didn't implement a stack, you just delegate everything to a python list, which already implements a stack. See @rightleg answer.

Answer (score 33):

From a pure Python standpoint, a list is already a stack if you narrow its methods down to only `pop` and `append`.
`l.append(x)` will put `x` at the end of the list, and `l.pop()` will remove the last element of the list and return it.

So generally speaking, when you need a stack in Python, you'll just make a list and use `append` and `pop`.
The same goes for queues, but you'd use `l.pop(0)` instead of `l.pop()`.

Considering this, I would say it's just plain unpythonic to implement a stack structure; instead, just use a `list`, that really is a dequeue and thus can be used as both a stack and a queue.

---

That said, I understand that `append` is not the common naming for the stack structure, and that `push` makes the intent of the method more clear.
Therefore, I would implement a stack as a direct subclass of `list`, and just "rename" the `append` method:

```
class Stack(list):
    def push(self, x):
        super().append(x)
```

If I wanted to make it more fool-proof, I'd also override `pop` so that it cannot take a parameter, unlike `list.pop`

```
class Stack(list):
    ...
    def pop(self):
        return super().pop()
```

Now the operation performed by the `peek` method can usually be done by `stack[-1]` (where `stack` is an instance of `Stack`), but it could be implemented just as follows:

```
class Stack(list):
    ...
    def peek(self):
        return self[-1]
```

---

*Addendum*

Some comments advising against subclassing `list` came out, notably mentioning the "composition over inheritance" principle.
That was an enriching discussion, and I'd like to amend my answer accordingly.

I'm no expert in design patterns, but as I understand it, this principle advocates the use of composition instead of inheritance to provide more flexibility.
One benefit of composition here is clearly to provide a cleaner API, with only the common stack methods and not `insert`, `remove` and so on that come from `list` and have no sense for stacks.

On the other hand, the inheritance I suggested happens to violate Liskov's substitution principle.
Although there's no problem with adding `push` and `peek` methods with respect to this principle, my implementation changes the signature of the `pop` method, which is not allowed by this principle.

From this perspective, I think that not only composition is valid here and adds in the benefit of a clean API, but also that inheritance is plain incorrect here.
Therefore, if I were forced to implement a stack class in Python, I'd go with composition and do as follows:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []

    def push(self, x):
        self._data.append(x)

    def pop(self):
        return self._data.pop()

    def peek(self)
        return self._data[-1]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)
```

But again, as I said, I would never do that in real life because a list can already serve as a stack, and `stack = []` would perfectly convey how `stack` would be intended to be used.

---

**References:**

On the Liskov substitution principle:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/56860/7051394

On composition over inheritance:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354/7051394 (also happens to mention Liskov principle)

Comment: Isn't `l.pop(0)` an O(n) operation?

Comment: Inheriting from list to implement a stack is pretty awful. The point of APIs is to provide specific limited, documented functionality. I don't want users to be able to access or modify the middle of my stack or be confused why my stack class even has this functionality. Whether you actually *need* a stack is a different question.

Comment: This suggestion to inherit completely fails "Composition over inheritance" principle.

Comment: @juhist I don't deny that your point is not valid, but I'm not sure I get it. In Python, a list is a collection to which elements can be appended, and from which elements can be removed in the inverse order of insertion - among other properties of course. From this standpoint, a stack is a kind of list as defined in Python. Therefore, it looks to me that inheritance is appropriate. What would be your arguments in favor of composition over inheritance, in this specific situation?

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for the feedback! I updated my answer, taking all this discussion into account. That was truly enriching, and I defintely learnt things today.

Comment: The argument is information hiding. By making the list a hidden implementation detail (preferably prefixed with underscore), a stack can be used only via its regular interface. The implementation is easier to change, too (for example, to linked list) if the implementation is not part of the interface.

Comment: For a queue, [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) would be best to avoid O(n) operations @MeesdeVries

Comment: `__len__` should be `len(self.data)`

Comment: @njzk2 ah definitely, my bad. Fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

On the whole the code is good, but I would look for three improvements:

1. **Information-hiding:** I would change `self.stack` to `self._stack` to indicate to readers of the code that this is an implementation detail that should not be accessed directly.  Reasons:

   1. Mutating `self.stack` directly, for example `self.stack.insert(2, 42)` could break the expectations a client would have of the stack.
   2. You might choose to use a different data structure in the future, so clients that depended on `self.stack` being a `list` would fail.
2. **Error handling:** popping or peeking on an empty stack will raise an `IndexError`.  It might be friendlier to raise a custom `EmptyStackError`, although a bare `IndexError` could still be ok, depending on ...
3. **Documentation:** ideally the code would have docstrings in accordance with [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).  Failing that, comments in the `pop` and `peek` methods explaining that an exception will occur on an empty stack are helpful to the reader, and document that the behaviour is intentional rather than a bug.

Comment: You seem to believe that in Python, information hiding is a goal in itself. [I would like to contest that.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html). If someone does (1), he's probably got a good reason for it, and otherwise deserves the exceptions he's gonna get. If someone wants (2), you can do exactly that with properties later on. Is there a place for `_name` in Python? Yes. But not for these reasons.

Comment: @Gloweye If I don't want people to rely on an implementation detail of my code, I use the [private variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) convention to indicate that to readers of the code.  As you say, it's up to them to respect the convention or not.  On (2), I don't see how a property would help - if the replacement data structure's API differed from `list` code that relied on the `list` API would still break.

Comment: A property can help because you can intercept the getting of `obj.name` and do whatever you want with it. Like return a proxy object with a list interface, if you care about that. But it's mostly that in basic python design, I think classes should be as simple as possible. Part of the beauty of python is that you don't -have- to make that sort of future considerations, because you don't lose any possibilities with NOT doing it. You're free to disagree, of course.

Answer (score 13):

The code is clean. My major concern with how it looks is that your naming doesn't follow PEP8. [Names should be snake_case, not camelCase.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) So `isEmpty` should be `is_empty`.

With how it works, I'd work on giving it consistent behavior with other collections.

Right now, you have a `sizeStack` method for returning the size. This should really be [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) instead:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.stack)
```

Why? Because now you can do this:

```
stack = Stack()
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
stack.push(3)
print(len(stack))  # Prints 3
```

You can now check the length using `len` like you can with `list` and other built-ins. `__len__` and other methods that start and end with two underscores are ""magic""; they have special meanings behind the scenes. Here for example, `len` just delegates to a classes's `__len__` method. I'd recommend looking over that page I linked to.

`isEmptys` could also be made a little more idiomatic by making use of the fact that empty lists are falsey:

```
def is_empty(self):
    return not self.stack
```

The major advantage here is nearly all collections are falsey when empty. With how you have it now, if you change what underlying structure your class uses, you'll need to remember to update the `is_empty` method, or `self.stack == []` will always fail.

And instead of having an `is_empty` method, it's more idiomatic to just have a `__bool__` method so your stack can be treated as a boolean value. See [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/232563/46840) answer to see how that can be done.

---

And `list` actually already has a `pop` method that does what you want. Your `pop` can just be:

```
def pop(self):
    return self.stack.pop()
```

Comment: instead of `is_empty`, one cane override the `__bool__` method. Or just leave it out, because with `__len__` implemented and no `__bool__` defined, `if stack` will internally call `if len(stack)`, which will call `if stack.__len__()` and use the fact that `0` is falsey.

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion I didn't see is that you can replace `isEmpty` with `__bool__`. Then, you can check whether the stack is empty with `if not stack`. This is more in line with other python collections.

Answer (score 1):

Overall looks good.  Your code does assume the user is keeping accurate track of the state of the stack.  I don't know the domain you're in here but that's something to keep in mind.
Some stack implementations throw a specific exception for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Pop and peek will crash with IndexError if applied to an empty stack. This may be acceptable (and is the only thing to do if you regard None as stack-able data), but otherwise you could add the lines

```
if not stack: # or, if stack == [] 
    return None
```

and in push

```
if data is None:
    raise ValueError( "Attempt to push data=None onto the stack" )
```

Comment: Throwing `IndexError` is what I would expect and similar to what happens if you'd try to call `pop()` on an empty list (`[].pop()` -> `IndexError: pop from empty list`).

Comment: Sure, but the question says "a stack". A refectory stack doesn't error, it just continues to exist in a state of emptyness. Neither is more correct than the other. Seems pointless to precisely re-inplement what is already provided as a standard `list` object.

Answer (score 0):

There are a three improvements I can think of:

- `self.stack == []` should be `not self.stack`
- Save the length of the list as you use the stack. That way, you can access the length in O(1)
- Make the variables private

This is what the code would look like at the end:

```py
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
        self.length = 0

    def isEmpty(self):
        return not self.stack

    def push(self, data):
        self.length += 1
        self.stack.append(data)

    def pop(self):
        self.length -= 1
        return self.stack.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.stack[-1]

    def sizeStack(self):
        return self.length
```